# Subsetting by variables within grouped observations R

Tags: r

so if you do this you'll get a data frame similar to what I am working with

```
test <- Indometh[Indometh$time %in% c(1.00,3.00,6.00),]
dil <- c(50,500,5000)
test$dilution <- dil
test <- test[-c(3,7,11,17),]
test[14,4] <- 50
test$time <- gsub(1, "run_1", test$time)
test$time <- gsub(3, "run_3", test$time)
test$time <- gsub(6, "run_6", test$time)


   Subject  time conc dilution
        1 run_1 0.48       50
        1 run_3 0.12      500
        2 run_1 0.70       50
        2 run_3 0.32      500
        2 run_6 0.12     5000
        3 run_3 0.22      500
        3 run_6 0.08     5000
        4 run_1 0.89       50
        4 run_6 0.07     5000
        5 run_1 0.39       50
        5 run_3 0.13      500
        5 run_6 0.10     5000
        6 run_1 0.84       50
        6 run_6 0.10       50
```

What I need to do is apply the following logic.

For each subject, if the dilution is 50 and there is any other dilution, keep the other dilutions.

If the dilution is 50 and there is only other dilution 50 available then keep all the dilution 50's for that subject.

so my resulting data frame should look like:

```
testres <- test[-c(1,3,8,10),]

 Subject  time conc dilution
       1 run_3 0.12      500
       2 run_3 0.32      500
       2 run_6 0.12     5000
       3 run_3 0.22      500
       3 run_6 0.08     5000
       4 run_6 0.07     5000
       5 run_3 0.13      500
       5 run_6 0.10     5000
       6 run_1 0.84       50
       6 run_6 0.10       50
```

Thanks

PS: It was hard wording this question, any recommendations for how I could of titled this question better?

Comment: Please print the `test` (or some part of it), and what do you want to receive.  From you text I am unable to understand what do you want.

Comment: Updated with a print out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` as well but a bit shorter:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    group_by(Subject) %>% 
    mutate(all50 = all(dilution == 50)) %>% 
    filter((all50 & dilution == 50) | (! all50 & dilution != 50))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   Subject   time  conc dilution all50
     <int> <fctr> <dbl>    <int> <lgl>
 1       1  run_3  0.12      500 FALSE
 2       2  run_3  0.32      500 FALSE
 3       2  run_6  0.12     5000 FALSE
 4       3  run_3  0.22      500 FALSE
 5       3  run_6  0.08     5000 FALSE
 6       4  run_6  0.07     5000 FALSE
 7       5  run_3  0.13      500 FALSE
 8       5  run_6  0.10     5000 FALSE
 9       6  run_1  0.84       50  TRUE
10       6  run_6  0.10       50  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Group the data frame by Subject
test2 <- test %>% group_by(Subject) 

# Filter Subjects with all dilution == 50
test3 <- test2 %>% filter(all(dilution == 50))

# Filter out other records with dilution == 50
test4 <- test2 %>%
  filter(!all(dilution == 50)) %>%
  filter(dilution != 50)

# Combine the data frames
test_final <- test3 %>%
  bind_rows(test4) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Subject = as.numeric(as.character(Subject))) %>%
  arrange(Subject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, .SD[(all(dilution == 50) & dilution == 50)|
         (!all(dilution == 50) & dilution !=50)], Subject]
#    Subject  time conc dilution
# 1:       1 run_3 0.12      500
# 2:       2 run_3 0.32      500
# 3:       2 run_6 0.12     5000
# 4:       3 run_3 0.22      500
# 5:       3 run_6 0.08     5000
# 6:       4 run_6 0.07     5000
# 7:       5 run_3 0.13      500
# 8:       5 run_6 0.10     5000
# 9:       6 run_1 0.84       50
#10:       6 run_6 0.10       50
```